# FrameworkReference vs PackageReference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, versioning

I recently had a version conflict of two different versions of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations` package (6.0.0.0 vs 7.0.0.0). I find those version conflicts hard to debug and explain, but I think the problem was that a `net6.0` class library used version 7.0.0.0 via `PackageReference` and the application that used the library included the 6.0.0.0 package via the SDK in the project file.

A collegue suggested to replace the `PackageReference` in the class library with `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. This seems to resolve the issue. As a side effect, we can remove other package references from the library, for example, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Options`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks`.

I like this solution, as it simplifies versioning and it makes other dependencies to 3rd party libraries easier to see. It also seems to prevent version conflicts.

Therefore, I am tempted to use the `FrameworkReference` for all class libraries that use any of the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` package, however, I am not sure about the consequences. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore) I found that consumers now need to install the ASP runtime instead of the .NET runtime. Are there other drawbacks, of which I am not aware of?

Comment: These are the drawbacks you can consider1)By using FrameworkReference, consumers of your class libraries will need to install the ASP runtime instead of the .NET runtime.2)FrameworkReference ties your class libraries to a specific version of the ASP runtime.3)FrameworkReference locks your class libraries to a specific set of dependencies provided by the ASP runtime4)While using FrameworkReference can simplify versioning within your class libraries, it may introduce additional complexity when managing dependencies across different projects or solutions.

Comment: "FrameworkReference ties your class libraries to a specific version of the ASP runtime". Isnt it the exact opposite? By using FrameworkReference, the lib always uses the version that is installed on the hosting machine. This means that it uses different versions on different machines and is not tied to a specific version.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the mistake. By using FrameworkReference, you can leverage the version of the ASP runtime that is available on the hosting machine, which provides flexibility and avoids version conflicts with Microsoft.Extensions packages. This approach allows your class libraries to adapt to the specific runtime version without requiring consumers to install additional dependencies.